# firewalld removing with all configurations using yum

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, firewalld

**Unfortunately** there is no -purge option as we all know in RHEL/Centos

I removed firewallD as usual with yum:

```
# yum remove firewalld -y
```

then flushed iptables. After installing firewallD again, surprisingly all configurations were reinstated as if it was never removed :)

**2 Questions:**

1. Is there any way to remove `firewallD` **civilized** way without chasing it with `rpm -qc` and `rpm -ql`?
2. Is there any way to flush all settings in `firewallD` as it was with `iptables` with `-F`, or at least flush all rich rules without typing full rule one by one?